# check binary integrity in golang

Tags: go

i try to create integrity protection of my application , this is my actual code :

```
package main 

import (
    "os"
    "io"
    "crypto/sha256"
    "fmt"
)


var OriginalSign string


func checkSUM() string {
    hasher := sha256.New()
    f, err := os.Open(os.Args[0])
    if err != nil {
        os.Exit(0)
    }

    defer f.Close()
    if _, err = io.Copy(hasher, f); err != nil {
        os.Exit(0)
    }

    return fmt.Sprintf("%x", hasher.Sum(nil))
}


func main() {
    signature := checkSUM()

    fmt.Println(OriginalSign)
    fmt.Println(signature)

    if signature != OriginalSign {
        fmt.Println("binary is compromised")
    }
}
```

i compiled with this command :

```
C:\Users\admin\go\src\localhost\lic>go build -ldflags="-s -w -X main.OriginalSig
n=8636cdeef255e52c6fd3f391fd7d75fbaf7c6e830e0e7ac66a645093c7efcbc7" -o checksum.
exe checksum.go

C:\Users\admin\go\src\localhost\lic>checksum.exe
8636cdeef255e52c6fd3f391fd7d75fbaf7c6e830e0e7ac66a645093c7efcbc7
d29440d3467f6176a6af0dcb61ea696cb318db3a6f1680b5b8f7890e165d8d7e
binary is compromised
```

how i can do this corectly in go ? i need to know signature of final binary file and check if is compromited.

Comment: I'm confused as to how you imagine this working, since adding a hash to a binary will of course change the binary. Regardless though, the binary can't verify itself, since if the binary is compromised then the checksum could be as well. What is the actual problem you're attempting to solve?

Comment: Use windows equivalent of `shasum -a 256` from the command line to get the string before compilation and then pass the resulting string to the compilation. That should be the string you're passing during the compilation process.

Comment: @JimB i want to check if binary is safe or compromited

Comment: @BelloDaniel: it makes no sense to trust the binary to tell you it's safe, since an unsafe binary could very well tell you the same thing. You need to use trusted external tools in some way. Most systems use a hash, as well as a cryptographic signature that can be verified.

Comment: Off-topic: if you're running Go >=1.8, `os.Executable` is preferred over `os.Args[0]`.

Comment: @Abdou how i can do this?

Comment: @EmilePels can show me example ? os.Open(os.Executable())  this not working

Comment: ``go tool buildid`` gives an id string which is generated when the binary is made.  I can't see how to detect tampering with this however

Comment: @Vorsprung, i cant't understend how can  `go tool buildid` help me ..can show me example ?

Comment: Why do you care if it's been tampered with? If someone takes your binary, modifies it, and runs it own their own system, why do you care what that binary does? This has the smell of an X/Y problem.

Comment: `buildid` can’t help you, because it’s not a way to verify a binary, it’s just an identifier. You need a chain of trust in order to have some sort of useful verification, and binary by itself has no chain of trust.

Comment: @JimB I agree it's not that useful but the contentid (or something like it) does seem to be what the question is about

Answer (score 0):

I can't see how to hook into tool buildid in a program but it can (kind of) detect changes to a binary

buildid does seem to store a "contentid" of the binary which is the essence of the original question

Here's a bash script that shows this (sorry I don't do MS Windows)

```
#

# delete any old binaries
rm -f t

# do an initial build
go build t.go

# show it works
./t

# get the original buildid
ORIG=$(go tool buildid t)

# now tamper with it!
perl -p -i -e 's/testing/porkpie/' t

# run again, show the tamper
./t

# now regenerate the buildid
go tool buildid -w t

# get the buildid after the regeneration
LATER=$(go tool buildid t)

# show the original and the post-tampering buildid - they are different
echo "$ORIG"
echo "$LATER"
```

Here's the do nothing t.go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("testing 123")
}
```

Here's the output

```
testing 123
porkpie 123
koB1H61TwQSHTQGiI4PP/-o93sSzqt1ltMhBJn4pR/2wvL4J9vF4vGUGjdbsyd/y-0uRBmxfJdrbAfsE1lr
koB1H61TwQSHTQGiI4PP/-o93sSzqt1ltMhBJn4pR/2wvL4J9vF4vGUGjdbsyd/UeLetY1pBF54B_4Y8-Nj
```

So the `go tool buildid` can store a hash in with the binary and (kind of) detect tampering.  But I couldn't work out how to get the contentid from a normal call inside a normal program